# What is the geometric meaning of this null-determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, interpolation, geometric-interpretation, interpolation-theory

While reading about interpolation I came across the following equation in
[Norlund](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN373206070?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B22%5D,%22panX%22:0.407,%22panY%22:0.598,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.548%7D).
It involves determinants and I don't understand it in full yet. I do know how *Lagrange* and *Newton* follow by using the *Laplace expansion*.

> $$
> P_n=-\det
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
> 1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
> 1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
> 1& x & \dots & x^n & 0\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> :
> \det
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n\\
> 1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> 1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

Where $P_n$ is the interpolation polynomial. Let's define the following for the interpolation polynomial $P_n(x_i)=y_i$ for $i\in[0,1,...,n]$. But this implies, after converting this equation into the determinant of a single matrix $A$, the following:

> $$
> \det(A)=\det
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
> 1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
> 1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
> 1& x & \dots & x^n & P_n\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =0\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
> $$

(**Question**) What is the geometric interpretation of this statement? My best guess is something along the lines of infinite solution because $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hypotesis, you have that

$$\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n\\
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$$

It means that

$$\ \text{rank} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n\\
\end{bmatrix}\  = n+1 = \text{rank} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n\\
1 & x & \ldots & x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\ $$ are both maximum. Now

$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
1& x & \dots & x^n & P_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

means that

$$ n+1 \leq \text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
1& x & \dots & x^n & P_n\\
\end{bmatrix} < n+2 \Rightarrow \text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \dots & x_0^n & y_0\\
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^n & y_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \dots & x_n^n & y_n\\
1& x & \dots & x^n & P_n\\
\end{bmatrix} = n+1$$

so the last column is linearly dependent from the other columns: $\exists \lambda_0, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (the coefficients of the interpolation polynomial!) such that $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \lambda_i x_j^i = y_j$ for all $j = 0, \ldots, n$ and $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \lambda_i x^i = P_n$.

Comment: Thanks! I like your reasoning, and I understand that the rank of the matrix $A$ is $n+1$ But could you elaborate your conclusion?

Comment: In this case, the rank is the maximum number of linerly independent columns; adding the "$y$-column" the rank doesn't increase, so the added column must be linearly dependent from the others.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration, I think I'll be able to understand it much better! PS. After refreshing linear dependance etc.

Comment: @Max how do you define the rank?

Comment: The number of linearly independent columns... So thanks!